# Woocommerce Dynamic cart/checkout inner block

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gutenberg-blocks

Facing issues when trying to create dynamic cart/checkout block.

So, the result desired is add a inner block lets say as a div and on the frontend display data in the div which is fetched from PHP.

Did try using ServerSideRender component but then was unable to define the 'render_callback' using the WooCommerce IntegrationInterface way.

Any doc or example of creating such a block will also be really helpful